# Javascript / jQuery two datepickers calculate date range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the Javascript below to calculate days out of a date range (2 Zebra Datepickers) and to pass the value to input field 'nights' .. then process a form.
While my Javascript works fine, i fail to achieve the same result with jQuery .val()

Javascript:

```
setDifference = function(form)
{
var x = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
var y = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
var arr1 = x.split('-');
var arr2 = y.split('-');
var dt1 = new Date();
dt1.setFullYear(arr1[2], arr1[1], arr1[0]);
var dt2 = new Date();
dt2.setFullYear(arr2[2], arr2[1], arr2[0]);
document.getElementById('nights').value = (dt2.valueOf() - dt1.valueOf()) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)
}
```

jQuery i tried so far:

```
$(function() {
            var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
            var endDate = $('#endDate').val();
            var dateSplit = startDate.split("-");    
            var dateSplit = endDate.split("-");        
            dateDiff = new Date(dateSplit[1] + " " + dateSplit[0] + ", " + dateSplit[2]);
            var dateDiff = new Date(endDate - startDate);
            var days = dateDiff/1000/60/60/24;

            $('#nights').val(days);
    });
```

Error i get is either 'NaN or 'invalid date' on all browsers i tried.

Comment: Why in one function you are dividing and in the other multiplying? far i remember you need to multiply to get this result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `dateSplit` two times. hence startdate and enddate would be same.

Comment: Oh. Yes, that's correct. i declared now startDateSplit endDateSplit + stDate enDate for 'new Date' and got it work. However, my only headache left is, how to pass the value of 'days' to my input field "#nights" -> $('#nights').val(days); I need the value as soon i select the second date only. Help?